# C# save game data to somewhere that users can't edit it

Tags: c#, windows, file, storage

I am working on a widows forms game, in which when a user passes a level the next level is unlocked, I want save the number of the current level to somewhere that a user can't edit it and cheat.Where should I save it and how? Please don't tell me to save it on web or on a database. thanks

Comment: I believe that [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) would be more appropriate for this kind of question.

Comment: @SuperOli no, it's more generic than just for games.

Comment: Basically, you can't. Anything your application does on a machine, can be analyzed and reverse engineered by someone who's determined enough. If you only care about non-tech-savvy users, store an encryption key in your application and encrypt the save file.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking, that is impossible. As long as the file exists on the hard drive, a user will be able to open it and modify its contents.

What you can do, however, is make it more difficult for the user to do so. Here's a couple of ways that would "slow down" a cheater:

1. Save the file in a location that is difficult to access. On Windows, the %AppData% folder might be the place to put it (it's a hidden folder in Windows). This really only stops people who don't know about the folder in the first place, though.
2. Write your save data in a way that is hard to reverse engineer. Perhaps you can write your file with an unusual extension to throw newbie cheaters off ("how do I open this 'special' filetype?" even though it's really just a text file that you can open in Notepad). Perhaps you can serialize the savedata object and then write it to a file.
3. If you want to pull out the big guns, you could encrypt the data somehow. Personally I think this is overkill for a non-multiplayer game, but it's certainly one way to solve the problem.

Unfortunately, the only way to guarantee the user won't modify the file contents is to save the file in a location that is not on the user's computer - a web server, for example.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is encrypt the whole string and save that in an encrypted file, keep the encryption key inside your code, then when you want to edit/read the written data you can simply use the same key to decrypt it. But any one can use any obfuscator tool and get the key.

Comment: Just a footnote: this is not safe, at all. Anyone with even the slightest bit of determination can reverse engineer this, as decompiling .NET assemblies and extracting strings (even after obfuscation) is trivial. All this really does is preventing users from simply editing the save file and changing "Unlockedlevel: 5" to "Unlockedlevel: 99". That may or may not be all OP is looking for.

Comment: Yeah I know, but it seems for me the simplest solution

Comment: _"I know"_ - then you might want to show that in your answer.